# can you define __doc__ directly?

Tags: python, docstring, f-string

I would like my docstring to be an f-string to put information on, but if I try to do that it isn't showed when you type `foo.__doc__` or `help(foo)`, so I tried the following:

used `.format()` which didn't register as a docstring

tried to do `self.__doc__ = f"""..."""`, but it still didn't work:

```py
def foo():
    self.__doc__ = f"""foo() is a function."""
    pass
```

I read on a site that it was possible to define the docstring without just putting a docstring at the beginning but it didn't say how.

How shall I start?

Comment: You can assign to the doc on a class using `classname.__doc__ = "whatever"`, and then `help(classname)` will include that string. Same with an instance of a class. Same with a function. What is the thing that you are trying to document?

Comment: You can use `type(self).__doc__ = "whatever"`

Comment: What exactly did you try that didn't work? Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: @khelwood I was writing what the function did, with some colours...!

Comment: @khelwood sure :)

Comment: @Barmar I will try that

Comment: `self` doesn't mean anything in your `foo` function. But you can just assign to `foo.__doc__`.

Comment: @khelwood yes I undersand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__doc__` is just an attribute. You can define it after defining your class / function / method :

```py
def func():
    pass

func.__doc__ = f"My function doc using fstring"

class Myclass:

    def my_method():
        pass

    my_method.__doc__ = f"My method doc using string"

Myclass.__doc__ = f"My class doc using fstring"
```

Calling `help()` on either `func`, `MyClass` or `my_method` will display your string.